# How do I merge Objects in a ArrayList?

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist

I have an arraylist of objects called Variable (ArrayList-Variable-) (The - is instead of the <, which otherwise will trigger the quote).
This Variable object has two fields: name and domain, where the name is a String and the domain is an array of int.
I want to merge the variables that have the same name, specifically I want to have a single variable with that name and with domain equal to the union of all the domains of the variables with the same name (without duplicates).

*For example:*

ArrayList : [VarA: 1, VarA: 6, VarB: 9, VarB: 3, VarA: 4, VarC: 2, VarC: 1]

What I would like to have is: [VarA: {1,6,4}, VarB: {9,3}, VarC: {2,1}]

How can I achieve that?

Comment: You said each object had an array of ints yet you only show one value per `Var` in your example.  That impacts any help that we might provide.  Please clarify.

Answer (score 1):

You can simply use *HashMap* to store such data
Let say variable for your *ArrayList* is **arr** then :-

```
HashMap<String, Set<Integer>> map = new HashMap<>();
for(Variable var:arr) {
   Set<Integer> set = map.getOrDefault(var.name, new HashSet<Integer>());
   set.add(var.domain);
   map.put(var.name, set);
}
```

Then **map** (*HashMap*) will contain desired results which you can convert if required like again to *ArrayList*.

Answer (score 0):

I would use a Hashmap of list to achieve that.

```
for (Tuple item: list) {
    if (!map.containsKey(item.key)) {
        map.put(item.key, new LinkedList<String>());
    }
    map.get(item.key).add(item.value);
}
```

Then using map.values() , you can recover a collection of the value Lists.

Answer (score 0):

With Java 8 Stream you can do it as below:

```
Map<String, Set<Integer>> result = v.stream().collect(
        Collectors.groupingBy(Variable::getDomain, 
            HashMap::new, Collectors.mapping(Variable::getVal, Collectors.toSet()))
      );
```

**Test Code:**

```
List<Variable> v = new ArrayList<Variable>();
v.add(new Variable("A", 1));
v.add(new Variable("A", 2));
v.add(new Variable("B", 4));
v.add(new Variable("C", 7));
v.add(new Variable("C", 7));

 Map<String, Set<Object>> result = v.stream().collect(
    Collectors.groupingBy(Variable::getDomain, 
        HashMap::new, Collectors.mapping(Variable::getVal, Collectors.toSet()))
  );
System.out.println(result);
```

**Output:**
{A=[1, 2], B=[4], C=[7]}

**Variable Class:**

```
class Variable {

  private String domain;

  private int val;

  public Variable(String domain, int val) {
    this.domain = domain;
    this.val = val;
  }

  /**
   * @return the domain
   */
  public String getDomain() {
    return domain;
  }

  /**
   * @param domain
   *          the domain to set
   */
  public void setDomain(String domain) {
    this.domain = domain;
  }

  /**
   * @return the val
   */
  public int getVal() {
    return val;
  }

  /**
   * @param val
   *          the val to set
   */
  public void setVal(int val) {
    this.val = val;
  }

}
```

Comment: The OP state in their question.   *the domain is an array of int.*

Comment: @WJS In example it mentions the ArrayList. And this is sample code, because conversion to-from array/list is quite simple.

Answer (score 0):

You already have a list? You can use groupingBy.

```
Map<String, List<Integer>> grouped = list.stream().collect( Collectors.groupingBy( Variable::getGroup ) );
```

Answer (score 0):

- this creates a `List` of some instances (records) that have duplicate values in the array for similar names.
- It uses a hashMap to store the name and domain by taking advantage of `computeIfAbsent` to first create the set if it doesn't exist, otherwise, add the arrays to it.  The purpose of the set is to eliminate duplicates.

```
// your list of objects each with a name and Integer[] domain   
List<Variable> vars = List.of(new Variable("var1", 1, 2, 3),
        new Variable("var2", 4, 5, 6), new Variable("var1", 1, 9, 10),
        new Variable("var5", 1, 6, 8), new Variable("var2", 4, 8, 9));
    
Map<String, Set<Integer>> result = new HashMap<>();
for (Variable v : vars) {
    result.computeIfAbsent(v.name, k -> new HashSet<>())
            .addAll(Arrays.asList(v.domain));
}
    
result.entrySet().forEach(System.out::println);
```

prints

```
var5=[1, 6, 8]
var2=[4, 5, 6, 8, 9]
var1=[1, 2, 3, 9, 10]
```

The Variable class per your description.

```
class Variable {
    private String name;
    private Integer[] domain;
    public Variable(String name, Integer... domain) {
        super();
        this.name = name;
        this.domain = domain;
    }
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
    public Integer[] getDomain() {
        return domain;
    }   
}
```

You can also do it using streams. I chose to use the `flatMapping` collector to combine the domain arrays into a set for each name.

```
Map<String,Set<Integer>> result = vars.stream().collect(
        Collectors.groupingBy(v->v.getName(),
           Collectors.flatMapping(
                   v->Arrays.stream(v.getDomain()),
                           Collectors.toSet())));
```

This yields the same as above.  Both of the above examples assume an Integer array to hold the domain items.  A `List<Integer>` would be even better.  Primitive arrays aren't readily supported by `Arrays.asList` or stream operations but there are workarounds.